# Ripple effect animation without touching

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, android-canvas, rippledrawable

I need to do some like ripple effect of `Listview` item background changing. I try to use `ObjectAnimator` like this:

```
AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(activity,
                    R.animator.animator_bkg);
            set.setTarget(childLinear);
            set.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            set.start();
```

R.animator.animator_bkg:

```
<objectAnimator
   android:propertyName="backgroundColor"
   android:duration="3000"
   android:valueFrom="@color/white"
   android:valueTo="@color/redTrans"
   android:repeatCount="-1"
   android:repeatMode="reverse"/>
```

It fluently changes a background (complete filling), but I need gradual filling of `ListView` item like ripple effect after touch the button.

I think, maybe I can use `Canvas` with overriding `onDraw`, but it's to hard for application and it can be some lags.

Comment: this will come automatically for lollipop devices. no?

Comment: this will come automatically for pre-lollipop devices too.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a custom view and implement the circular transition in onDraw(), but it's complicated.

You can work around the complexity by using `ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal()` on sub view. But the draw back is that it's only for API 21+.

In few words, your root layout of the cell has to be a `FrameLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`.
When the transition starts, you dynamically add 2 views under your cell with the start and the end color, then transition with the circular reveal between the 2. At the end of the transition, you just remove the 2 sub views to keep the view hierarchy a bit cleaner.

Here is the result :

[image: Color reveal]

In code :

Cell layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/cell_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cell_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="#FF00FF">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is content"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Code that trigger the background transition :

```
private void changeBackgroundColor() {
    final FrameLayout startingColorFrame = new FrameLayout(mCellRoot.getContext());
    final FrameLayout endingColorFrame = new FrameLayout(mCellRoot.getContext());
    startingColorFrame.setBackground(mCellContent.getBackground());
    endingColorFrame.setBackground(mPendingColor);
    mCellContent.setBackground(null);
    endingColorFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mCellRoot.addView(endingColorFrame, 0, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mCellRoot.addView(startingColorFrame, 0, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    int finalRadius = (int) Math.sqrt(mCellRoot.getWidth()*mCellRoot.getWidth() + mCellRoot.getHeight()*mCellRoot.getHeight());
    final int sourceX = mCellRoot.getWidth() / 3;
    final int sourceY = mCellRoot.getHeight() / 2;
    // this is API 21 minimum. Add proper checks
    final Animator circularReveal = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(endingColorFrame, sourceX, sourceY, 0, finalRadius);
    endingColorFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    circularReveal.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(final Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            mStartButton.setEnabled(true);
            mCellContent.setBackground(mPendingColor);
            mPendingColor = startingColorFrame.getBackground();
            mCellRoot.removeView(startingColorFrame);
            mCellRoot.removeView(endingColorFrame);
        }
    });
    // customize the animation here
    circularReveal.setDuration(800);
    circularReveal.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    circularReveal.start();
}
```

Comment: Then re-implement the reveal effect in Canvas. Only way. For pre-lollipop, you can just have a smooth color transition with an Animator and an ArgbEvaluator.

Comment: Or use a community compat version of Circular Reveal like https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal